# How to update openParentApplication for Watch OS 2?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2, watchos

I have a watch app that needs to communicate with the parent app to get some information. This should happen while only using the watch and the phone in a pocket. It used to work like this:

In the InterfaceController on the watch:

```
[InterfaceController openParentApplication:request reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {
     // handle response from phone
}];
```

In the AppDelegate of the phone:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply 
    NSDictionary *response = // generate response
    reply(response);
}
```

I tried to change the code in the InterfaceController to:

```
[[WCSession defaultSession] sendMessage:request
                replyHandler:^(NSDictionary *reply) {
                }
                errorHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                }
];
```

And the code in the AppDelegate to this which never seems to get called:

```
- (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)message replyHandler:(void (^)(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *replyMessage))replyHandler {
     // this never gets called
}
```

I've seen examples of using sendMessage on the watch, but they all require the delegate to be in a ViewController on the phone that is open. Is there a way to get information from the parent app on the phone while the phone is not being used?

Answer (score 0):

If this helps anyone, I figured out that you have to run it on the main thread.

```
- (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)message replyHandler:(void (^)(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *replyMessage))replyHandler {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // do stuff here
        replyHandler(replyDictionary);
    });
}
```

Comment: My replyHandler works fine on any thread. Perhaps the generation of your replyDictionary requires the main thread?